# ASP.NET MVC Cascading Dropdownlists with JQuery and Keeping State on Postback

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have an inventory create view which cascades with the following: select an item category > item (gets populated by jquery when category selected) > building > room (populated when building selected) and then enter a quantity. On submit, if the model is not valid and it returns to the create screen, all of the drop down lists are reset. What I am trying to do is the model is invalid, say if I didn't select a room, I still want my selections for category, item and building to remain. Perhaps I should go about a different way of populating these drop down lists (I've never done this before, so maybe I'm missing a "standard" for doing this)?

[Inventory Create Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hNQBY.png)

InventoryViewModel

```
public class InventoryViewModel
{

    public IList<SelectListItem> BuildingNames { get; set; }
    public IList<SelectListItem> RoomNames { get; set; }
    public IList<SelectListItem> CategoryNames { get; set; }
    public IList<SelectListItem> ItemNames { get; set; }
    public int InventoryItemID { get; set; }

    public virtual Item Item { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Item")]
    [Required (ErrorMessage="You must select an item.")]
    [Range(1, Int32.MaxValue, ErrorMessage="You must select an item.")]
    public int ItemID { get; set; }

    public virtual Room Room { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Room")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "You must select a storage room.")]
    [Range(1, Int32.MaxValue, ErrorMessage="You must select a room.")]
    public int RoomID { get; set; }

    [Range(1, Int32.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "You must enter a quantity greater than 0.")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "You must enter a quantity.")]
    public int Qty { get; set; }
    public DateTime UpdateDT { get; set; }
    public string UpdateBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreateDT { get; set; }
    public string CreateBy { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        var itm = GetCreateInventoryViewModel();
        return View(itm);
    }

    private InventoryViewModel GetCreateInventoryViewModel()
    {
        List<SelectListItem> buildingNames = new List<SelectListItem>();

        List<SelectListItem> categoryNames = new List<SelectListItem>();

        InventoryViewModel itm = new InventoryViewModel();

        List<Building> buildings = db.Buildings.ToList();
        buildings.ForEach(x =>
        {
            buildingNames.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = x.Name, Value = x.BuildingID.ToString() });
        });

        itm.BuildingNames = buildingNames;

        List<ItemCategory> categories = db.ItemCategories.ToList();
        categories.ForEach(x =>
        {
            categoryNames.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = x.Name, Value = x.ItemCategoryId.ToString() });
        });

        itm.CategoryNames = categoryNames;
        return itm;
    }
   [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GetRoom(string buildingId)
    {
        int buildId;
        List<SelectListItem> roomNames = new List<SelectListItem>();
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(buildingId))
        {
            buildId = Convert.ToInt32(buildingId);
            List<Room> rooms = db.Rooms.Where(x => x.BuildingID == buildId).ToList();
            rooms.ForEach(x =>
            {
                roomNames.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = x.Name, Value = x.RoomID.ToString() });
            });
        }
        return Json(roomNames, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GetItem(string categoryId)
    {
        int catId;
        List<SelectListItem> itemNames = new List<SelectListItem>();
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(categoryId))
        {
            catId = Convert.ToInt32(categoryId);
            List<Item> items = db.Items.Where(x => x.ItemCategoryID == catId).ToList();
            items.ForEach(x =>
            {
                itemNames.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = x.Name, Value = x.ItemID.ToString() });
            });
        }
        return Json(itemNames, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

View (and jquery)

```
 @model EventsWebsite.Models.InventoryViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="box">
            <div class="box-header with-border">
                <h3 class="box-title">New Inventory Item</h3>
            </div>
            @using (Html.BeginForm())
            {
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

                <div class="box-body">
                    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

                    @Html.ValidationMessage("Error", new { @class = "text-danger" })

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label" for="ddlCategory">Category</label>
                        <div>
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.CategoryNames, Model.CategoryNames, "---Select---", new { @id = "ddlCategory", @class = "form-control" })
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ItemID, "Item", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                        <div id="Item">
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.ItemNames, new List<SelectListItem>(), "---Select---", new { @id = "ItemID", @class = "form-control", @name = "ItemID" })
                        </div>
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ItemID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label" for="ddlBuilding">Building</label>
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.BuildingNames, Model.BuildingNames, "---Select---", new { @id = "ddlBuilding", @class = "form-control" })
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RoomID, "Room", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                        <div id="Room">
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.RoomNames, new List<SelectListItem>(), "---Select---", new { @id = "RoomID", @class = "form-control", @name = "RoomID" })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RoomID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Qty, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                        <div>
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Qty, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Qty, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="box-footer">
                    @Html.ActionLink("Cancel", "Index", null, new { @class = "btn btn-default" })
                    <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" />
                </div>
            }

        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#ddlBuilding').change(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                url: "/Inventory/GetRoom",
                data: { buildingId: $('#ddlBuilding').val() },
                datatype: "json",
                traditional: true,
                success: function (data){
                    var room = "<select id='RoomID' name='RoomID' class='form-control'>";
                    room = room + '<option value="">--Select--</option>';
                    for(var i=0; i < data.length; i++)
                    {
                        room = room + '<option value=' + data[i].Value + '>' + data[i].Text + '</option>';
                    }
                    room = room + '</select>';
                    $('#Room').html(room);
                }
            })
        });

        $('#ddlCategory').change(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                url: "/Inventory/GetItem",
                data: { categoryId: $('#ddlCategory').val() },
                datatype: "json",
                traditional: true,
                success: function (data) {
                    var item = "<select id='ItemID' name='ItemID' class='form-control'>";
                    item = item + '<option value="">--Select--</option>';
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                        item = item + '<option value=' + data[i].Value + '>' + data[i].Text + '</option>';
                    }
                    item = item + '</select>';
                    $('#Item').html(item);
                }
            })
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You need to populate your SelectLists in the POST method. Refer the controller code in [this DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1bPZym)

Comment: Thank you so much for providing that example, I was able to apply it to my project successfully!